# Restrict user to install software in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts

I am using Windows 7 and have two user accounts on the machine:

1. CJ - Administrator
2. Others - Basic

I would like to configure the system so that the "Others" account can't install any software. In the past I have used gpedit.msc to block usage of msiexec.exe, but it didn't help now. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: what version of Windows 7 do you have?

Comment: Just use the group policy editor.

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-prevent-users-from-installing-programs-in-windows-7 - this was the first link when googling `windows 7 block software install`

Answer (score 0):

Simply set UAC to its most strict setting.